# Angular Material 2 MdMenu unit test case failing. Error: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am using angular-cli to create my component and working with Material2.

In test.component.html

```
<md-toolbar>
<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="anchorMenu" aria-label="Open anchor menu">
  <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
</md-toolbar>

<md-menu #anchorMenu="mdMenu"> //getting error on this line
<a md-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items" href="http://www.google.com" [disabled]="item.disabled">
  {{ item.text }}
</a>
</md-menu>
```

While Unit Testing:

> Error: Error in ./TestCompComponent class TestCompComponent - inline
>   template:7:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of
>   undefined

Everyhing works fine when I run **ng serve** but getting above error on **ng test**

In test.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import 'hammerjs';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MaterialModule],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Some answers said "fixture.detectChanges();" will work but this is already present and not working for me. Some more answers said need to add Observable but I am not using any service. This is simple MdMenu from Material2.

Debugging:

1. When I remove [mdMenuTriggerFor]="anchorMenu" and md-menu reference
   I am not getting any error in Unit testing.
2. When I am removing "ui-test-comp" tag from
   app.component.html I am not getting this error and all test cases
   are getting pass.

Please find plnkr link for all related file reference. (Please note that this is not working plnkr and just for reference purpose.)

https://plnkr.co/edit/AFzHWG28ZYgLZTs5aZgF

Comment: I am able to fix this issue with workaround given by Shaxx here.. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1913. But still looking for correct way to fix it.

Comment: Isherwood, I hope you did not understand my comment. I am saying I found a workaround which is definetly not a solution and still looking for solution.